# Detect/get captured values of a lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda

Is there a way to detect and/or retrieve the values captured in a lambda function, statically or dynamically ?

Example, for the use case :

```
randomFunction([this](){ methodCall(); });
```

Is this possible ?

```
void randomFunction(std::function<void()> lambda) {
    ... // Detect if lambda capture is 'this'
    MyClass* obj = /* retrieve lambda capture 'this' */;
    ...
}
```

Let's say *MyClass* is known, will always be the same, and all of this occurs in a template function. Is there at least some traits/tricks to distinguish which template function to call according to the lambda captures ?

Comment: From your use case, you should probably use `void randomFunction(std::function<void(MyClass*)> lambda, MyClass* obj)`

Comment: Can you get the contents of a `std::function`? Yes. Can you get the contents of a lambda? No.

Comment: Of course there is tons of way to achieve the same result. I just find `randomFunction(this, [this]{ methodCall(); });` redundant

Comment: The whole purpose of `std::function` is to implement type erasure. Now you want to un-erase the erased type. Whatever you're trying to do, you need to solve the real problem correctly, instead of trying to figure out how to do this, which you think is the solution to your problem. It is not.

Answer (score 0):

You have captured `this`, so why not just return it from the lambda?  Of course chaos will ensue if the corresponding object is not accessible anymore.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class MyClass;

void randomFunction(std::function<MyClass*()> lambda)
{
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
  MyClass* obj = lambda();
}

class MyClass
{
public:
  void methodCall()
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
  }

  void test()
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    auto lambda = [this]() { methodCall(); return this; };
    randomFunction(lambda);
  }
};


int main()
{
  MyClass mc;
  mc.test();
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vwsM7FulvfdbUu8r)</kbd>

Comment: The problem is I don't want to evaluate the lambda at this moment (I store it actually). In the end, this is just a matter of syntaxic sugar, not a big deal.

Comment: @LD_FLO A lambda stores its capture as datamembers (because it is essentially an unnamed struct with call operator).  How these members are stored is an implementation detail and therefore you cannot access them.